# Button in title bar how to reach it

Tags: android, tabactivity, titlebar

When creating a titlebar with a button, which is common in all activities e.g. title bar created in tabactivities. how is it possible to reach the button in all of the sub activities??

```
public class tabActivity extends TabActivity  implements OnClickListener{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    c = this;
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.tabactivity);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Settings",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.preferences)).setContent(
                    new Intent(this, Settings.class)));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("About",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newspaper)).setContent(
                    new Intent(this, About.class)));
```

This is here where i initialize my tabs, and the custom title with buttons..

And in this class i would like to reach the buttons in the custom title.:

```
public class About extends Activity 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.about);

    ImageView imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Position);
    imag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("heeey");
        }
    });

}
```

The listener doesnt work??

Hooow is this possible??

Comment: I reposted details on original post. see there and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Android_templateActivity extends Activity
{
private static OnClickListener listener;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View v = new View(this);

    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Android_templateActivity.listener.onClick(v);
        }
    });
}

public static void setListener(View.OnClickListener listener)
{
    Android_templateActivity.listener = listener;
}
}
```

this is main activity

```
public class aaa extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    Android_templateActivity.setListener(this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

this is subactivity

Comment: I have done it exactly the same way.. But im wondering where you declare the specific button to listen to?? in the example i gave it was R.id.position?? where would you put this.. Im very new to android..

Comment: in code above "View v = new View(this); " this line shoud be a such line that finds your button declared in your layout xml line button = findViewById(R.id.btn) blah blah..

Answer (score 3):

Make an abstract `Activity` like this:

```
public abstract class MyAbsActivity extends Activity {
    abstract public void buttonClickedInTab();
}
```

Then extend your both child `Activity` of tabs with `MyAbsActivity`, then you have to override `buttonClickedInTab()` method.

While overriding the method put your logic there for both Activities. for example your `About` with `buttonClickedInTab()` should look like:

```
public class About extends MyAbsActivity {

    //onCreate() etc here

    @Override
    public void buttonClickedInTab() {
        //Your logic to do action for About
    }

}
```

Repeat this for other `SettingActivity`.

Now in your `TabActivity` where you handle the title button event `onClick()`

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    MyAbsActivity activity = (MyAbsActivity)getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
    activity.buttonClickedInTab(); // it will inform the current activity
}
```